# How to divide each column by the average three columns that precede it?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the unemployment levels of Austria between 2006 and 2012. I would like to divide the unemployment of each year with the average of the three years that preceded. For, example the variable would show at the year 2010: the unemployment in 2010 divide by the mean of unemployment in 2007,2008 and 2009. Is there a way to do it in dplyr?

I know that the following code divides each year by the first three years of the variable. But i am not sure how to do it with the 3 years that preceded it:

```
mydata %>% 
  mutate(
    unemp_3 = unemp - mean(unemp[1:3])
    )
```

Here is my data:

```
structure(list(cntry = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = "Austria", class = "factor"), unemp = c(5.2, 4.9, 
    4.1, 5.3, 4.8, 4.6, 4.9), year = 2006:2012), row.names = c(NA, 
    -7L), groups = structure(list(cntry = structure(1L, .Label = "Austria", class = "factor"), 
        .rows = structure(list(1:7), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
        "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the question subtracts the mean but the question and subject indicate you want to divide by the mean so we will assume that divide is what you want.

Use rollapplyr to calculate the rolling mean. list(-seq(3)) means use offsets -1, -2 and -3, i.e. the 3 prior values.  For example, 5.3 / mean(c(5.2, 4.9, 4.1))
gives the 2009 value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

mydata %>%
  group_by(cntry) %>%
  mutate(unemp_3 = unemp / rollapplyr(unemp, list(-seq(3)), mean, fill = NA)) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  cntry   unemp  year unemp_3
  <fct>   <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
1 Austria   5.2  2006  NA    
2 Austria   4.9  2007  NA    
3 Austria   4.1  2008  NA    
4 Austria   5.3  2009   1.12 
5 Austria   4.8  2010   1.01 
6 Austria   4.6  2011   0.972
7 Austria   4.9  2012   1.
```